# How to pass a 2D pixel array to BitmapSource.Create()?

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have a 2D array of byte pixels from which I want to create a BitmapSource. Given BitmapSource.Create() requires a 1D array plus stride, how should I pass my 2D array?

My current solution is to use BlockCopy to copy to an intermediate 1D array:

```
int width = pixels2D.GetLength(1); int height = pixels2D.GetLength(0);
byte[] pixels1D = new byte [width * height ];
Buffer.BlockCopy(pixels2D, 0, pixels1D, 0, pixels1D.Length * sizeof(byte));
return BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Gray8,
                        null, pixels1D, stride: width * sizeof(byte));
```

but this relies on what I understand to be undefined packing of array dimensions. I would like a solution that avoids this, and ideally avoids copying the data. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there are three methods to implement this：

1）`Block Copy`， which is efficient；

2）`For loop`， to copy `pixels2D[i,j]` to `pixels1D[i*width+j]`, which is also efficient;

3) `Linq`, `pixels2D.Cast<byte>().ToArray()`, which is simple but slow.

Comment: it will be better if you could add some code snippet too.